# Stackdriver Logging Request/Response with Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am running the predict function through the API Call against a model deployed in Cloud MLEngine and I have enabled logging so that I can see the logs in Stackdriver Logging.

When I go to the logs I see the logs generated are like this

```
{
 httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.002585s"   
  remoteIp:  "X.X.X.X"   
  requestMethod:  "POST"   
  requestSize:  "259"   
  requestUrl:  "ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/models/pricing_model/versions/v1:predict"   
  responseSize:  "56"   
  status:  200   
  userAgent:  "google-cloud-sdk gcloud/202.0.0 command/gcloud.beta.ml-engine.predict invocation-id/XXXXXXXXX environment/None environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/2.7.14 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 16.7.0),gzip(gfe)"   
 }
 insertId:  "qd41"  
 jsonPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.ml.v1.PredictionLogEntry"   
  modelLatency:  "0.000507s"   
  numInstances:  "1"   
  requestType:  "LOADED"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/<project-id>/logs/ml.googleapis.com"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-05-23T20:51:42.980326893Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type:  "cloudml_model_version"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 timestamp:  "2018-05-23T20:51:42Z"  
}
```

This does not include the request and response. Is there a way I can add that parameter in so that whenever I run predict against the model in ML Engine, I can also see the request and response?

I would like to see two more fields in the logs like this

```
request:[1068,34,45,89,3245,543543]
prediction(or Response):[34354.43]
```

Comment: This feature is not currently available. We'd love to better understand your requirements. Do you mind sending and email to cloudml-feedback@google.com to start a discussion?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sure, I will.

Comment: A feature request was created for you on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/110515033). You can star this feature request to show your interest and get updates on it.